# XSLT processing with Qt

Tags: qt, xslt

I like to display some (X)HTML content in a Qt application using QtWebKit.
The content should be generated from XML documents via XSLT.

As I am new to Qt, my questions are as follows:
1) Can QtWebKit display XML documents with the xml-stylesheet element set?
2) Can Qt apply XSLT to an XML document and return the result as a string or write it to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QtWebKit and xslt were always seprate, combining them was always a todo - not sure what the current status is but you can easily test it with the examples.

Or follow http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2010/03/03/qtwebkit-releases/

Comment: I tried Qt's browser demo today. It is capable to apply XSLT if the xml-stylesheet element is set, but there seems to be no way to dynamically set the element without changing the underlying xml data.

Answer (score 13):

With `QXmlQuery` you can process a XML document against a XSL template and then pass the result to the `QWebView::setHtml(QString)` (recent versions of Qt will use [`QWebEngineView::setHtml(..)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#setHtml).

```
QString out;
QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);
query.setFocus(QUrl("myInput.xml"));
query.setQuery(QUrl("myStylesheet.xsl"));
query.evaluateTo(&out);
webview->setHtml(out);
```

You can find this code and more information in the [QXmlQuery documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlquery.html#running-xslt-stylesheets).

Comment: Is it possible QXmlQuery to resolve the xsl links embedded in the XML file instead of calling setQuery?. I mean, in your code snippet, if "myInput.xml" contains the link to the XSL file, and the XSL file also contains references to other XSL files in a recursive way, how could QXmlQuery be applied to load all stylesheets? May it already do this? Or is setQuery always required? (in such case one should scan the XML and XSL files for building a dependency tree or something like that).

Comment: @Claudix, if your question is still valid, consider [asking it as a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). And yes, it is possible.